# Does Jython have a ternary operator?

Tags: jython

Does Jython have a ternary operator?
I was unable to find it in the [guide](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/ed1.0/chapter3/).
edit: I am using weblogic's jython 2.2.1

Comment: Yes, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/407651

Comment: @mzjn, I am asking about jython not python

Comment: Jython implements the same language as "standard" Python (aka CPython). There is no special syntax in Jython that isn't available in CPython.

Comment: See https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LangSyntax/#the-difference-between-jython-and-python

Comment: it looks like the version am using doesn't have it. Do you care to formulate an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a if condition else b` syntax was added to the language [in version 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions). It is available in both CPython and Jython.

Jython 2.2.1 is too old and does not support this syntax.